# Taylor series for exponential map on "famous" manifolds (as the sphere)

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, taylor-expansion, riemannian-geometry, spheres

I read many papers and books that give a Taylor series for the exponential map on a smooth manifold $(\mathcal{M},\nabla)$ e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.2868v1. It can be possible to find somewhere explicit formulas of that series for manifold as the 2D sphere, also up to the $2^{nd}$ order? Thank you!

Comment: Can't the exponential map on $S^2$ be explicited easily? Given a point $x\in S^2$ and a tangent vector $v$, the geodesic starting from $x$ at initial velocity $v$ is $c(s)=\cos(s)x+\sin(s)v$.